# react-router-dom not working when refreshing page from mobile device

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react-router-dom when refresh the page from mobile device on every page and when I want to click the url: http://kafalovgroup.bg/contacts or http://kafalovgroup.bg/about I receive: `Error 404 Not found`.

When click on http://kafalovgroup.bg/ and switch the pages from the menu I not have a problem.

All pages in my react project are in one file app.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">

        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/"><span className="logo">"ФИНИШ ГРУП" ЕООД</span></Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav> 
                    <Link to={'/'} className="nav-link">НАЧАЛО</Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav> 
                      <Link to={'/services'} className="nav-link">УСЛУГИ</Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav> 
                      <Link to={'/gallery'} className="nav-link">ГАЛЕРИЯ</Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav> 
                      <Link to={'/contacts'} className="nav-link">КОНТАКТИ</Link>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav> 
                      <Link to={'/about'} className="nav-link">ЗА НАС</Link>
                    </Nav>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

        <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
                <Route exact path="/services" component={Services}>
              <Services />
              </Route>
                <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery}>
              <Gallery />
              </Route>
                <Route exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts}>
              <Contacts />
              </Route>
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About}>
              <About />
              </Route>
            </Switch>

        <header className="App-header">
        </header>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Under this code I have a other functions to other pages like:

```
 function Home() {
      return (
      <div className="firstPageDiv">
        <div className="contentFirstPage">
          <p>First Page</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    }

function Services() {
  return <div className="servicesPageDiv">
    <div className="contentServicesPage">
        <div className="servicesText">
          <p> Second Page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this error and can I get some example how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the server. Basically it tries to resolve  http://kafalovgroup.bg/contacts but it is not found so it send 404 response.

The solution is to setup your server to send always the main page, the one that renders `App`.

How are you serving this page?

Comment: What can I do when I click on http://kafalovgroup.bg/contacts to load contacts page .. ?

Comment: How are you serving the react app?

Comment: I not understand what you mean, at the end of the code I have "export default App;"
I run the app with npm start and deploy with npm run build.. 
I'm not very familiar with the language and I don't understand your question. Sorry for that :)

Comment: I mean if you run `npm run build` it will generate a folder named `build` with index.html inside and so on. How are you serving this page to the web? Are you using express.js? Apache2? nginx?

Comment: I archive build folder and upload .zip file here: https://www.superhosting.bg/ I don’t know what they used. If it solve the problem I will ask them ?

Comment: I don't know honestly, I have very little experience with both node.js and apache2. I would know how to do that in node.js but not in apache2/nginx. The basic concept is that you need to serve to every request `index.html` except for files that are actually present. But still this is something related to server, not react.js.

Comment: perhaps you could talk with superhosting.bg support team if you're not administrating your domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234037/discussion-between-pizhev-racing-and-zeno-dalla-valle).